# Pivot table macro is not running with excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

i am using excel 2016 and created macro to generate pivot table but when i share and run same file in my coworker laptop with excel 2013 it pop up with error i tried changing verion 6 to version 15 but same error please help me out with this

i tried as below;

```
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
  
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!A1:AB" & lastRow).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Sheet3!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable2"`
```

but error is popping there is problem with version or maybe with pivot table name. how can i resolve this issue, is it not possible to run vba code made by excel 2016 in excel 2013?

Comment: lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!A1:AB" & lastRow, Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet3!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=8         i tried this one also but not getting solution

Comment: Please don't put code as comment. Instead, edit your question and add it there. And add the error message (and the exact statement where the error occurs).